# How to discourage distracting behaviour by a teenager?

Tags: beginner, etiquette

I’m showing a 12 year old male how to play chess.  While he has amazing abilities, he plays with the captured pieces, jumps around, leans over the board, knock pieces over that are still on the board.  Yes, distracting but what can I best say to him that would motivate him to learn the importance of not distracting an opponent?

Answer (score 5):

Anybody who has taught boys of this age will recognize some form of attention deficit disorder in this behaviour. To some extent this is only minimally in the child's control. No explanation or instruction you can give will change this to any extent.

The standard response is to medicate with Ritalin however this is not something I would condone. All of my sons were "diagnosed" with ADD by teachers at their schools. They were right about one of them but in no case would I or my wife agree to medication.

What worked with the son who probably really did have ADD was more exercise, a lot more exercise. He ended up in the town swimming team swimming something like 20 hours a week at his peak. At that level of physical activity the ADD behaviour pretty much disappeared. He just didn't have the energy.